# How many ways can you give out 4 oranges, 2 bananas and 2 lemons so that everyone get 2 fruits and nobody gets 2 oranges

Tags: combinatorics

**How many ways can you give out 4 oranges, 2 bananas and 2 lemons so that everyone get 2 fruits and no one  gets 2 oranges**

My solution:

Ok so if no one can have 2 oranges, everyone gets 1 in every case.

1) OB OB OL OL

2) OL OL OB OB

3) OB OL OB OL

4) OL OB OL OB

5) OL OB OB OL

6) OB OL OL OB

**= 6 ways**

I wonder if someone knows a more "mathematically" approach to solve this problem.

Comment: As much as you can, you should avoid brute force by listing out every possibility.  It is... acceptable... for such a small problem like this, but as soon as the numbers change to ones which are larger then this becomes entirely infeasible.

Comment: When you don't got brains, you use brute force ;)

Comment: By "nobody gets two oranges" I presume you mean "nobody gets two *or more* oranges"... right?

Comment: That is implied when everyone gets 2 fruits...right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your problem, you know that every person has to get an orange and one other fruit. Then your problem reduces to "In how many ways can we give two bananas to 4 people?" In this case is equivalent to "In how many ways can we give two lemons to 4 people?"The answer is $$\binom 42=6$$

Answer (score 2):

Each person gets 1 orange.
The remaining fruit can be divide up into $$\binom{4}{2,2} =6$$ ways, as by definition this is the number of ways of splitting 4 things into two groups of two (google the “choose” function for more on how this works)